# Using the natural language toolkit in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Hello I am am trying to use the nltk to tokenize and generate some pos tags but I get error response in spite of of importing the nltk

```
bs=BeautifulSoup(web.text, 'html.parser')
print (bs) 
tokes=nltk.word_tokenize (bs)
tags= nltk.pos_tag(tokes)




TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-f1434047d3f5> in <module>()
      1 bs=BeautifulSoup(web.text, 'html.parser')
      2 print (bs)
----> 3 tokes=nltk.word_tokenize (bs)
      4 tags= nltk.pos_tag(tokes)
      5 tags

C:\Users\DESDEJEI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py in word_tokenize(text, language)
    104     :param language: the model name in the Punkt corpus
    105     """
--> 106     return [token for sent in sent_tokenize(text, language)
    107             for token in _treebank_word_tokenize(sent)]
    108 

C:\Users\DESDEJEI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py in sent_tokenize(text, language)
     89     """
     90     tokenizer = load('tokenizers/punkt/{0}.pickle'.format(language))
---> 91     return tokenizer.tokenize(text)
     92 
     93 # Standard word tokenizer.

C:\Users\DESDEJEI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in tokenize(self, text, realign_boundaries)
   1224         Given a text, returns a list of the sentences in that text.
   1225         """
-> 1226         return list(self.sentences_from_text(text, realign_boundaries))
   1227 
   1228     def debug_decisions(self, text):

C:\Users\DESDEJEI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in sentences_from_text(self, text, realign_boundaries)
   1272         follows the period.
   1273         """
-> 1274         return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]
   1275 
   1276     def _slices_from_text(self, text):

C:\Users\DESDEJEI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in span_tokenize(self, text, realign_boundaries)
   1263         if realign_boundaries:
   1264             slices = self._realign_boundaries(text, slices)
-> 1265         return [(sl.start, sl.stop) for sl in slices]
   1266 
   1267     def sentences_from_text(self, text, realign_boundaries=True):

C:\Users\DESDEJEI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1263         if realign_boundaries:
   1264             slices = self._realign_boundaries(text, slices)
-> 1265         return [(sl.start, sl.stop) for sl in slices]
   1266 
   1267     def sentences_from_text(self, text, realign_boundaries=True):

C:\Users\DESDEJEI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in _realign_boundaries(self, text, slices)
   1302         """
   1303         realign = 0
-> 1304         for sl1, sl2 in _pair_iter(slices):
   1305             sl1 = slice(sl1.start + realign, sl1.stop)
   1306             if not sl2:

C:\Users\DESDEJEI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in _pair_iter(it)
    308     """
    309     it = iter(it)
--> 310     prev = next(it)
    311     for el in it:
    312         yield (prev, el)

C:\Users\DESDEJEI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in _slices_from_text(self, text)
   1276     def _slices_from_text(self, text):
   1277         last_break = 0
-> 1278         for match in self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text):
   1279             context = match.group() + match.group('after_tok')
   1280             if self.text_contains_sentbreak(context):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

could anyone help me figure out where exactly i may have gone wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `bs` to the tokenize function when you should be passing `bs.text`